# Why wouldn't my Sidebar open when calling a function from my custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this piece of code of mine :

My Custom Hook :

```
export const useSidebar = () => {
  const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(false);

  const toggleSidebar = useCallback(() => {
    setShowSidebar(!showSidebar);
  }, [showSidebar]);

  return [showSidebar, toggleSidebar] as const;
};
```

My Sidebar :

```
export const Sidebar = () => {
  const [showSidebar, toggleSidebar] = useSidebar();

  return (
    <aside
      className={`top-0 right-0 w-[35vw] bg-blue-600  p-10 pl-20 text-white fixed h-full  ease-in-out duration-300 z-panel ${
        showSidebar ? 'translate-x-0 ' : 'translate-x-full'
      }`}
    >
      <button
        className="flex text-4xl text-white items-center cursor-pointer fixed right-10 top-6 z-50"
        onClick={() => toggleSidebar()}
      >
        x
      </button>

      <h3 className="mt-20 text-4xl font-semibold text-white">I am a sidebar</h3>
    </aside>
  );
};
```

When I call `toggleSidebar()` from my hook, my sidebar doesn't show up. The debugger indicates that `showSidebar` is always `false`.

Could you point to me what I'm doing wrong ?

Many thanks.

[Run on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5hfxyz?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fsidebar.tsx)

Comment: Hi, i forked you Stackblitz project, an i think it is CSS Problem and not React. Please verify: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5hfxyz-dfdmm9 (The show showSidebar variable is alternating correctly). All I did was remove some CSS classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my mistake I could not use hooks for that, so I went with a context.

```
export type SidebarContextType = {
  isVisible: boolean;
  toggleSidebar: () => void;
};

export const SidebarContext = createContext<SidebarContextType | null>(null);

export const SidebarProvider = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  const toggleSidebar = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('--', !isVisible);
    setIsVisible(!isVisible);
  }, [isVisible]);

  return <SidebarContext.Provider value={{ isVisible, toggleSidebar }}>{children}</SidebarContext.Provider>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It can be help

```
  const toggleSidebar = useCallback(() => {
    setShowSidebar(!showSidebar);
  }, [showSidebar]);
```

I think that the problem is dependencies

Comment: That's not it, with or without the useCalllback I have the same issue. But you're right about the empty array part !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I think the first problem is dependency and the second problem is your CSS. I am not good about Tailwind CSS (If you use), but tried with bg colors ```showSidebar ? 'bg-blue-600  ' : 'bg-blue-100 '  ``` and the sidebar works. I could not understand where did I click in the map, the sidebar had to work?